# Reversing a hash function

Tags: c#, algorithm, hash

I have the following hash function, and I'm trying to get my way to reverse it, so that I can find the key from a hashed value.

```
uint Hash(string s)
{
    uint result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        result = ((result << 5) + result) + s[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

The code is in C# but I assume it is clear.

I am aware that for one hashed value, there can be more than one key, but my intent is not to find them all, just one that satisfies the hash function suffices.

**EDIT :**

The string that the function accepts is formed only from digits 0 to 9 and the chars '*' and '#' hence the Unhash function must respect this criteria too.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Is there any limit to the length of the string that is input?

Comment: Not a homework, and I suppose the limit do not exceed a dozen of characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute force should work if uint is 32 bits.  Try at least 2^32 strings and one of them is likely to hash to the same value.  Should only take a few minutes on a modern pc.

You have 12 possible characters, and 12^9 is about 2^32, so if you try 9 character strings you're likely to find your target hash.  I'll do 10 character strings just to be safe.

(simple recursive implementation in C++, don't know C# that well)

```
#define NUM_VALID_CHARS 12
#define STRING_LENGTH 10
const char valid_chars[NUM_VALID_CHARS] = {'0', ..., '#' ,'*'};

void unhash(uint hash_value, char *string, int nchars) {
  if (nchars == STRING_LENGTH) {
    string[STRING_LENGTH] = 0;
    if (Hash(string) == hash_value) { printf("%s\n", string); }
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VALID_CHARS; i++) {
      string[nchars] = valid_chars[i];
      unhash(hash_value, string, nchars + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Then call it with:

```
char string[STRING_LENGTH + 1];
unhash(hash_value, string, 0);
```

Answer (score 8):

This should reverse the operations:

```
string Unhash(uint hash)
{
    List<char> s = new List<char>();
    while (hash != 0)
    {
        s.Add((char)(hash % 33));
        hash /= 33;
    }
    s.Reverse();
    return new string(s.ToArray());
}
```

This should return a string that gives the same hash as the original string, but it is very unlikely to be the exact same string.

Comment: Well, it's not working, because I believe that there is a sum of result within each iteration, there are other constraints too, this function accepts only 0 to 9 and '*' and '#' in its input, see the edit above :)

Comment: +1.  It's working for me.  Here's a test (C# 4.0 required) -> `Parallel.For(uint.MinValue, uint.MaxValue, currentValue => { Debug.Assert(Hash(Unhash((uint)currentValue)) == currentValue, "Test failed: " + currentValue.ToString()); });`

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham yes the decoding is correct, but I need the value to contain only digits 0 to 9 and '*' and '#' since the only possibility of input is on a phone

Comment: @martani_net: Your question is ambiguous as to whether you need your `Unhash` function to satisfy those critieria for its output, or merely that the strings you are feeding into `Hash` would meet them.  Note that you can still run my test on either type of solution.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham right, I just corrected the question, the unhash function must meet those criteria too

Answer (score 3):

Characters 0-9,*,# have ASCII values 48-57,42,35, or binary: 00110000 ... 00111001, 00101010, 00100011

First 5 bits of those values are different, and 6th bit is always 1. This means that you can deduce your last character in a loop by taking current hash:

```
uint lastChar = hash & 0x1F - ((hash >> 5) - 1) & 0x1F + 0x20;
```

(if this doesn't work, I don't know who wrote it)

Now roll back hash,

```
hash = (hash - lastChar) / 33;
```

and repeat the loop until hash becomes zero. I don't have C# on me, but I'm 70% confident that this should work with only minor changes.

Answer (score 2):

Hash functions are designed to be difficult or impossible to reverse, hence the name (visualize meat + potatoes being ground up)

Comment: I will now feel hungry every time I use a dictionary!

Comment: If that is the true etymology of the word "hash" as it pertains to computer science (I don't know, as I don't have an academic background in it)... well, that is **awesome**.

Answer (score 0):

I would start out by writing each step that `result = ((result << 5) + result) + s[i];` does on a separate line.  This will make solving a lot easier.  Then all you have to do is the opposite of each line (in the opposite order too).

Comment: I did that, but the problem is that you don't have the last character to start with!

Comment: and you never will, so you have to skip that.